# Finite-dimensional representations of the integers

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, linear-transformations

Two questions.

1. How do I find all finite-dimensional linear representations of $\mathbb{Z}$, the additive group of the integers? I know that all finite-dimensional differentiable representations of the reals under addition are given by sending $t$ to $\exp(tA)$ where $A$ is a linear operator on the vector space of given dimension. So I can restrict those representations to the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$, but are there more?
2. What about the integers $\mod m$ under addition? How do I find all their finite-dimensional linear representations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figuring this out for $\Bbb Z$ is easy because the group $\Bbb Z$ is generated by the single element $1$.  In particular, for any representation $\rho:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$, the following holds:

- $\rho(1)$ is an invertible matrix
- for any $k \in \Bbb Z$, we have
  $$
  \rho(k) = \rho(k \cdot 1) = \rho(1)^k
  $$

Thus, every representation of $\Bbb Z$ can be written in the form
$$
\rho(k) = A^k
$$
where $A$ is an invertible matrix.  Moreover, if we can find a matrix $B$ for which $\exp(B) = A$ (which we can, as long as $A$ is invertible), then this becomes
$$
\rho(k) = \exp(kB)
$$
so indeed every representation has the form you mentioned.

---

$\Bbb Z_m$ also is generated by $1$, but it has the additional property that $m \cdot 1 = 0$.  Thus, the representations of $\Bbb Z_m$ are precisely those of the form
$$
\rho(k) = A^k
$$
for which $A^m = I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix).  If $C$ is one of the "logarithms of the identity" (i.e. $\exp(C) = I$), then we can get the representation
$$
\rho(k) = [\exp(C/m)]^k = \exp[(k/m)C]
$$

Comment: Could you give me the matrix $\rho (1)$ explicitly  please?

Comment: why $\rho (k .1 ) = \rho (1) ^k$?

Comment: @hopefully To your first question: every invertible matrix will work.  If you want a faithful representation, then $\rho(1) = 2I$ will work, for example.   To your second: this is the definition of a representation, i.e. the definition of a homomorphism.  Perhaps you should make your own post where you detail what exactly you're confused about.

Comment: why every invertible matrix will work?

Comment: why for a faithful representation $\rho (1) = 2I$ will work?

Comment: @hopefully that's too much to answer in a comment. As I said, you should post your own question

Comment: I have posted it but they voted that it is not good question.

Comment: Okay I will write a question and put a link for you here

Comment: Here is my questions .... I hope you have enough time to answer it for me https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080770/finite-dimensional-representations-of-the-integers-2