# Finite-dimensional representations of the integers (2)

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I was reading the answer of the question from this link:

[Finite-dimensional representations of the integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093731/finite-dimensional-representations-of-the-integers)

But I have 2 things that I do not understand in the solution and the comments of the above link:

1- In case of $\mathbb{Z}$, why every invertible matrix will work?

2- why for a faithful representation $\rho (1) =2I$ will work?

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: It is very hard to figure out precisely what you are looking for as it is just a matter of checking definitions.

Comment: okay for the first question which definition should I check ? @TobiasKildetoft?